# Issues with @Transactional not working in Spring Boot

Tags: java

In this code I am doing transactional testing using @Transactional annotations. It defines two transactional methods A() and B(), and two data insertion test methods trueA() and errorB(). The trueA() method will not throw an error, while the errorB() method will fail to insert due to the name field of UserEntity being too long.

In this test, method A() calls trueA() to insert a record and then throws a RuntimeException, which is caught by try...catch. Method B() also calls trueA(), and calls errorB(), with try...catch to catch any exceptions.

What puzzles me is that in method B(), after the errorB() method throws an exception, shouldn't the catch block in B() catch that exception? But in reality it caused the rollback of the trueA() method.

```
@Transactional
public void A() {
    try {
        // 执行一些数据库操作
        trueA();

        // 抛出异常
        throw new RuntimeException("Exception occurred");
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        // 捕获异常并进行处理
        System.out.println("Exception caught: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    
}
    
@Transactional
public void B(){
    try {
        /**
         * 没有异常
         */
        trueA();
        /**
         * 执行异常
         */
        errorB();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception caught: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
    
    
public void trueA(){
    UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
    userEntity.setName("ceshi");
    em.merge(userEntity);
}
    
    
public void errorB(){
    UserEntity userEntity1 = new UserEntity();
    userEntity1.setName("ceshi111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111");
    // 字段超长报错
    em.merge(userEntity1);
}
```

But using the following approach, method B() will not rollback:

```
@Transactional
public void B(){
    try {
        trueInsert();
        errorInsert();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception caught: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void trueInsert(){
    jdbcTemplate.execute("INSERT INTO `test`.`user` ( `name`, `password`) VALUES ( 'xuzili222', '11');");
}

public void errorInsert(){
    jdbcTemplate.execute("INSERT INTO `test`.`user` ( `name`, `password`) VALUES ( 'xuzili2211111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111112', '11');");
}
```

PS: If the length of the user.name field is too long, the insert will fail.

Comment: So what do those non-english comments say? I'm not sure if it's relevant to the question but if we know what the comments claim each bit should do then we might identify the issue easier.

Comment: Can you add the code of `UserEntity`?

Comment: This is the project URL: ssh://git@git.jetbrains.space/xuzili/main/java-jpa.git